# How to purchase consumable prduct multiple times?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Hi I am beginner in IPhone developing.
and I want to integrate in app purchase in my Iphone application,
currently I have one consumable product, 
and I want to user buy that one consumable product multiple times, so can any one give me the sample code or hint for this issue, how to purchase one consumable product multiple times?

Comment: non-consumable means you can buy again and again...

Comment: Is your problem solved by this tutorial??

Answer (score 3):

Here is the good tutorial for in app purchase.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation